# Как задать стиль стиль последней кнопке в списке. CSS & HTML

Tags: html, css

Всем привет. Подскажите пожалуйста, у меня есть такая HTML конструкция и мне нужно задать стиль, именно последнему в этом списке  что бы не сделал , задает именно всем. Спасибо заранее и всем хорошего дня.

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <button>
     </button>
  </li>

  <li>
    <button>
     </button>
  </li>

  <li>
    <button>     <----Ему
     </button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос решён:

```
li:last-child button {}
```